# Main list value changes when used in variable that instantiates list

Tags: java, python, arrays, arraylist

How to create a list that can not change its values, for example, i have that for loop in java:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                if (i != j) {
                    List<Integer> vizinhoAplicacao = new ArrayList<>(ordemAcoes); //HERE
                    vizinhoAplicacao.set(i, vizinhoAplicacao.get(i) + 5);
                    vizinhoAplicacao.set(j, vizinhoAplicacao.get(j) - 5);
                    calcularRetornoAnual(vizinhoAplicacao, contatorVizinho, numeroSimulacao);
                    contatorVizinho++;
                }
            }
        }
```

The value of ordemAcoes always stays the same as it goes into the loop,
But when I make the same scenario using python, the ordemAcoes changes as I make changes to the object I declare using it, what I want to do is not to change the value of ordemAcoes, so that every time I enter the loop, I has the same values as before.

```
    for i in range(0, 5):
        for j in range(0, 5):
            if (i != j):
                neighborAplication = actionOrder #HERE is the list
                neighborAplication[i] = neighborAplication[i] + 5
                neighborAplication[j] = neighborAplication[j] - 5
                returnCalculateY(neighborAplication, countNeighbor, simulationNumber)
                countNeighbor += 1
```

Result in Java:

```
[35, 20, 20, 15, 10]
[35, 25, 15, 15, 10]
[35, 25, 20, 10, 10]
[35, 25, 20, 15, 5]
```

Result in Python:

```
[35, 20, 20, 15, 10]
[40, 20, 15, 15, 10]
[45, 20, 15, 10, 10]
[50, 20, 15, 10, 5]
```

I want to have the same result also in python, however the list actionOrder value changes when I use neighborAplication.

Comment: Longshot: does `neighborAplication = actionOrder[:]` fix it?

Comment: I'll try this option thankss!

Comment: I'll write an answer explaining why this fixes the problem - IF it fixes the problem. :)

Comment: The problem is that you create new list in Java by doing `new ArrayList<>(ordemAcoes)`. When you mutate this list, it won't touch `ordemAcoes`. In Python, you just assign your list to a new variable. So when you mutate `neighborAplication`, you are actually mutating the same list as `actionOrder`. You therefore need to create a copy of the `actionOrder` list before mutating it. See this post for how to fix it in Python: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2612815/4137489

Comment: Yes, I managed to understand this relationship, thank you, the option that the timgeb gave worked perfectly !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that with

```
neighborAplication = actionOrder
```

you are just creating another reference with the name `neighborAplication`, and
 [assignment never copies data](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html). When you mutate `neighborAplication` or `actionOrder`, the change will be seen across both names, because in-memory there only exists one list.

Use

```
neighborAplication = actionOrder[:]
```

in order to create a (shallow) copy of your list.

See [How to clone or copy a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list) for additional details.